# Unable to validate GraphQL query containing variables

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I am trying to validate a GraphQL mutation with variables and I am not clear on how to define variables - the moment I declare a variable in the query it fails validation. I am not sure where the issue is:

#### Schema

```
input ItemCreateInput {
  clientMutationId: ID
}

type Mutation {
  itemCreate(input: ItemCreateInput): ItemCreatePayload!
}
```

#### Query

```
mutation {
  itemCreate(
    input: $input
  ) {
    ids
  }
}
```

#### Variables

```
{
 "input": {
    "clientMutationId": 1575680625627
 }
}
```

This rejects with `Variable \"$input\" is not defined.`. But I am confused because the [validate](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/validation/#validate) function does not accept variables as parameter so why is it validating them?

Where is the issue? how can I correctly define and pass variables?

Comment: As the error indicates, the variable you are trying to use is not defined. Variables must be defined as part of the operation definition if they are used inside the operation.

Comment: An thank you. I hadn't really grasped what the docs where saying till I read that post.